# Форматированное считывание файла в textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Открываю файл .с, он отформатирован( переносы строк и так далее)
пробовал и так

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
            TextBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
```

и так

```
TextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
```

все равно все  в куче.
в то время как считывание в richTexbox

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

работает нормально.
Как считать файл  в texbox?

Comment: @Deathlike, а в текстбоксе включено свойство "Разрешать многострочный текст" (Multiline)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/12w624ff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Конечно включено

Comment: @Deathlike, тогда должно работать, разве что еще эти свойства могут сбивать текст в кучу:AcceptsReturn, AcceptsTab, WordWrap. Хотя первые два служат для ввода, а не для отображения...

Comment: По изменял во всех возможных положениях эти свойства не помогает.
вот такая каша в texboxE
http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/3/1/5/Untitledjp_4541022_12051315.jpg
а так в richtexbox
http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/3/2/7/richtextjp_8110880_12051327.jpg

Comment: Пробовал у себя файлы cpp и cs. Все работает. Предлагаю обходной путь: считывать файл построчно и добавлять перенос, а затем засунуть полученный массив в свойство Lines. примерно так:

textBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Select(a => a + Environment.NewLine).ToArray();

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В файле скорее всего окончания строк в стиле unix - `"\n"`. TextBox поддерживает только переносы строк в стиле Windows - `"\r\n"`. И поэтому воспринимает и показывает весь текст как одну строку.

Проверить это можно открыв тот же файл в notepad - текст точно так же свернет в одну длинную строку.

Решение - использовать `File.ReadAllLines` или `File.ReadLines` для построчного чтения текста. Оба метода поддерживают unix line endings. Прочитанные строки можно или склеить помощью системного разделителя:

```
textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines(filename));
```

или отдать в `TextBox` как отдельные строки:

```
textBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
```